# Is there a word for the definition of an event?

Tags: word-request

Let's say an event organisation creates the concept of a new event where people gather to listen to music. It's going to be a recurring event taking place once every year. Whenever that event takes place, we call that 'an event'. Is there also a word for the concept/definition of the event? So not any of the instances of it, but rather the concept of it.

Update: It's not necessarily a musical event. It could be the concept of an outdoor activity. It could be the concept of prize winning pumpkins held annually. It could even be a recurring event where people are not gathering, but I can't think of an example yet.

Comment: Is it a recurring event to which a name has been assigned? For example, *Burning Man*?

Comment: Great example. Thank you. I changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: So you are looking for a *generic* term which means "a periodically recurring event where people come to attend performances"?

Comment: Yeah. Or rather: "a periodically recurring event where people come to gather"

Comment: But you want it to be generic, so that it could encompass *Burning Man* as well as an annual county fair where people come to see prize winning pumpkins and sheep and to eat a lot of unhealthy foods?  Not sure what you mean by "come to gather".

Comment: I hope you're not trying to name a table in SQL.  :)

Comment: @TRomano Bingo!

Comment: You can call it RecurrentEventDefinition. Table names can consist of more than one word, and they don't need to follow the rules of natural language. The price of admission column would be in the RecurrentEventInstances table.

Comment: This comment thread is just funny :D.

Comment: @TRomano I could. But I always favour a word over a word combination if one exists and as long as the word is not contrived. For example. For describing a human in an sql database, I would use a table called Genome instead of HumanDefinition. I hope a non-contrived word exists for EventDefinition as well.

Comment: It doesn't exist.  The level of abstraction you need is not one that would occur in natural language.  We don't typically have a single word that would encompass things as disparate as music festivals, political rallies, raves, etc, where "people gather".  Perhaps **Gatherings** might do, since it is an abstraction formed from the verb.  But absent a context it could refer to anything that gathers or can be gathered, fabric, pieces of board games, people, herds of animals, tribal councils, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably refer to such an event as a [festival](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/festival) - an organised series of events, typically held annually in the same place.

In the past it was often used to describe the annual celebration of a special time of year (for example, *harvest festival*), nowadays it is often used to describe
more modern events, such as a music festival.

A quite famous example would be the [Glastonbury Music Festival](http://www.glastonburyfestivals.co.uk) - an annual music in the UK since 1970.

The term can also be used to describe a multitude of other annual events. To give but a few examples:

> - [Sarasota Pumpkin Festival](http://www.sarasotapumpkinfestival.com)
> - [Clarenbridge Oyster Festival](https://www.facebook.com/clarenbridgeoysterfestival)
> - [South African Cheese Festival](http://www.cheesefestival.co.za)
> - [Great American Beer Festival](https://www.greatamericanbeerfestival.com)

Comment: Thanks. But it's not necessarily a musical event. I wasn't clear about this in my question. It could be the concept of an outdoor activity. It could be the concept of prize winning pumpkins held annually. It could even be a recurring event where people are not gathering, but I can't think of an example.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify on the definition of the word, but if you *are* naming an SQL table, then it's not really a question on English anymore :) It's more a question of clarity and structure, and TRomano's suggestions provide both.